# How to find a match in a list of LxWxT where Positions of L and W can vary

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have been given the following Problem: We need to find out if a given combination of Length, Width and Thickness might have a rawmaterial on stock. 
As Input I get the following String:

> "L:90 W:40 T:8"

For Rawmaterials I have created a small dataclass:

```
Public Class RawMatInfo

    Private _length As String
    Private _width As String
    Private _thickness As String

    Public Property Length As String
        Get
            Return Me._length
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._length = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Width As String
        Get
            Return Me._width
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._width = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Thickness As String
        Get
            Return Me._thickness
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._thickness = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Here is some Sample raw material data:

```
    Dim RawMatInfo As New List(Of RawMatInfo) From {
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "20",
        .Thickness = "3"},
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "20",
        .Thickness = "8"},
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "90",
        .Thickness = "8"},
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "100",
        .Thickness = "8"},
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "120",
        .Thickness = "8"},
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "140",
        .Thickness = "8"},
        New RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "260",
        .Width = "190",
        .Thickness = "3"}
        }
```

I have used 0 in length as wildcard because the raw material has theoretically infinite length. Because Length and Width are exchangable, the result for "L:90 W:40 T:8" has to be

```
RawMatInfo With {
        .Length = "0",
        .Width = "90",
        .Thickness = "8"}
```

So how do I get the right Rawmaterial out of the collection if one exists? I Tried several LINQ ways, but they all appeared MUCH to complicated. Here is one I tried:

```
Public Function GetRawMaterial(ByVal description As String) As RawMatInfo

    Dim tmpString = Split(description)
    Dim DescriptionDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each KVP In tmpString
        If InStr(KVP, ":") > 0 Then
            Dim tmpKVP = Split(KVP, ":")
            DescriptionDict.Add(tmpKVP(0), tmpKVP(1))
        End If
    Next

    If DescriptionDict.ContainsKey("T") Then
        If DescriptionDict.ContainsKey("W") Then
            If DescriptionDict.ContainsKey("L") Then

                Dim RawMat = RawMatInfo.Where(Function(x) x.Thickness = DescriptionDict("T"))
                If RawMat.Count > 0 Then
                    RawMat = RawMat.Where(Function(x) x.Width = DescriptionDict("W") Or x.Length = DescriptionDict("W") Or x.Length = "0")
                    If RawMat.Count > 0 Then
                        RawMat = RawMat.Where(Function(x) x.Width = DescriptionDict("L") Or x.Length = DescriptionDict("L"))
                        If RawMat.Count > 0 Then
                            Return RawMat
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I Hope someone can help me to find an efficient way of doing this and loosen the knob in my brain

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. The only thing, you could just add the condition in just one sentence: `Dim RawMat = RawMatInfo.Where(Function(x) x.Thickness = DescriptionDict("T") AndAlso (x.Width= DescriptionDict("W") Or x.Length = DescriptionDict("W") Or x.Length = "0") AndAlso ...)`

Comment: OK so you say this is the right way to go? Thanks for the fast answer, wrote it like you proposed. I just thought there might be a much better and more efficient way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you input is a string don't use string for lengths, lengths are not strings they are numbers and your class should reflect that, its a model of something.

Also if you want to compare to instance of the same class the logic usually goes into that class or an implementation on IEqualtyComparer.

My vb is too rusty but in C# it would look like this.

```
public class RawMatInfo : IEquatable<RawMatInfo>
{
    public RawMatInfo(decimal length, decimal width, decimal thickness)
    {
        Length = length;
        Width = width;
        Thickness = thickness;
    }

    public RawMatInfo(string input)
    {
        var values = input.Split(' ').ToDictionary(x => 
            x.Split(':').First(), x => x.Split(':').Last());
        Length = Convert.ToDecimal(values["L"]);
        Width = Convert.ToDecimal(values["W"]);
        Thickness = Convert.ToDecimal(values["T"]);
    }

    public decimal Length { get; }

    public decimal Width { get; }

    public decimal Thickness { get; }

    public bool Equals(RawMatInfo other)
    {
        if(other == null) return false;
        return Length == other.Length 
            && Width == other.Width
            && Thickness == other.Thickness;
    }
}
```

Then you can just make a list and see if it is in there:

```
var list = new List<RawMatInfo>
{
    new RawMatInfo(90, 40, 8),
    new RawMatInfo(100, 40, 8),
    new RawMatInfo(90, 40, 10),
};  

var search = new RawMatInfo("L:90 W:40 T:8");
var match = list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Equals(search));
```

Comment: I really like this solution, but you missed some requirements, like L and W can be exchanged and L:0 as a wildcard. I added this and came up with the following for the Equals: `return (Length == other.Length || Length == other.Width || Length == 0) && (Width == other.Length || Width == other.Width) && Thickness == other.Thickness;`